# Ajax call in React Starter Kit

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-starter-kit

I'm using [React Starter Kit](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit) to create my first React app, and I'm struggling with Ajax calls. I saw that this Kit embeds a way to perform Ajax calls (which is by the way used internally for app routing):

```
import fetch from '../../core/fetch';
```

I've added this in my component, and then try to perform an Ajax call when the component loads. Here is my code:

```
  componentDidMount() {

      var moduleManager = 'https://my_domain.com/my_endpoint';

      async function getModules (url) {
          const response = await fetch(url);
          const content = await response.json();
          return content;
      };

      this.state.modulesList = getModules(moduleManager);

      console.log(this.state.modulesList);
  }
```

I'm also using the state value in my render function:

```
  render() {
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.modulesList.length; i++) {
        rows.push(
            <li>{this.state.modulesList[i]}<li/>
        );
    }
```

This code put together logs this in my console:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

Then the Ajax call is performed (successfully) and my console is now showing this:

```
Promise
__proto__:Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]:"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]:Array[16]
```

The desired behaviour is of course to update my view: when the ajax calls is performed, display one line per array member.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I suggest doing:

```
constructor() {
  ...
  // Bind your async function to your stateful component's class
  this.getModules = this.getModules.bind(this);
}

async getModules(url) {
  try {
    // Perform the ajax call
    const response = await fetch(url);

    // Convert respone to json
    const content = await response.json();

    // Process your content (if needed)
    ...

    // Call setState() here
    this.setState({someContent: content});

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getModules(`${URL}`);
}
```

You can't actually return the fetched/parsed data from an `async` function. According to [this MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), `async` function returns a `promise`, and not the actual data you'd expect to get after parsing it.

What happened in your case, was that you were actually trying to receive a returned value from an `async` function, inside a regular(sync) function (componentDidMount). You can either do what I suggested, or use `.then()` to use `setState` after resolving and parsing the promise, in the actual `componentDidMount` function.

I suggest reading about `async` functions and `Promise` before continuing.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks, the setState did it!

Answer (score 0):

Without testing your code, one problem is that you're incorrectly [modifying `state` directly](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). That doesn't trigger a `render` and therefore your view is not updated. Try `setState()` instead, like so:

```
<li>{this.setState({modulesList[i]})}<li/>
```